# UPSERTing with TitanDB

Tags: titan

I'm having my first steps as a TitanDB user. That being, I'd like to know how to make an upsert / conditionally insert a vertex inside a `TitanTransaction` (in the style of "get or create").

I have a unique index on the vertex/property I want to create/lookup.

Comment: Transactionality guarantees are governed by your storage backend in Titan. Which are you using?

Comment: I'm using Cassandra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a one-liner "getOrCreate" for Titan 1.0 and TinkerPop 3:

```
getOrCreate = { id ->
  g.V().has('userId', id).tryNext().orElseGet{ g.addV('userId', id).next() }
}
```

As taken from the new TinkerPop ["Getting Started" Tutorial](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.1.0-incubating/tutorials-getting-started.html).  Here is the same code translated to java:

```
public Vertex getOrCreate(Object id) {
  return g.V().has('userId', id).tryNext().orElseGet(() -> g.addV('userId', id).next());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, but that looks like Groovy or something. How do I use that from within Java?

Comment: added translation to java - not that different

Comment: so, you need to call a get first and then add the Vertex? 
There is no automatic way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Roughly speaking, every Cassandra insert is an "upsert". If you look at the [Titan representation](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/data-model.html) of vertices and edges in a Cassandra-like model, you'll find vertices and edges each get their own rows. This means a blind write of an edge will have the given behavior you're looking for: what you write is what will win. Doing this with a vertex isn't supported directly by Titan.

But I don't think this is what you're looking for. If you're looking to enforce uniqueness, why not use the `unique()` modifier on a Titan composite index? (From the [documentation](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html#_composite_index)):

```
mgmt.buildIndex('byNameUnique', Vertex.class).addKey(name).unique().buildCompositeIndex()
```

With a Cassandra storage backend, you need to enable [consistency locking](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/eventual-consistency.html). As with any database, managing the overhead of uniqueness comes at a cost which you need to consider when writing your data. This way if you insert a vertex which violates your uniqueness requirement, the transaction will fail.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian. I'm already using `unique()` on a composite index, which leads me to the behaviour you describe: "if you insert a vertex which violates your uniqueness requirement, the transaction will fail." This is exactly what I want to avoid with an upsert. Do you have any idea on how I can achieve this ("update this vertex, creating it if it doesn't exist yet").

Comment: Why not let the built-in locking behavior do your work for you? The work done under the covers using their locking protocol is likely to be as efficient as anything you  could put together. You could always query for the vertex, and if you find it, update it.